# Android Collaborate Git with google play services maps

Tags: android, eclipse, git, google-maps, google-play-services

I have a problem.
We are a students group, who are developing a Android Project. We use Eclipse and git (bitbucket) to share project in three different computers.
Our project uses google maps, and we had to get a key to use google maps.
We don't know how we can share this project by git (between ourselves). Do we need new key?

Does anyone have an example of this problem? 
Does anyone know a guide?

Thanks.

Comment: Google Maps Keys are per application, not per user. As you are developing on the same application, you only need 1 Google Maps Key.

There is nothing specific you need to do to share the project.

Comment: Thanks @pdegand59. We upload the sources to bitbucket, and in another computer, i pull it, but the project have errors in android_manifest in this element: `<meta-data 
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Comment: We use another project like a library. This project's name is: google-play-services_lib. When we share our project, this library isn't share. We don't know how include in the same project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, We face the same problem too.

Maybe "use the same keystore which generates the map-api-key for all the team members while building apk" is a workaround.

Comment: When I have some time I'll explain what happened to me.